# Rails Redactor Gem, rich text editor adding annoying 'br' tags

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redactor, redactor.js

Trying to use this [gem](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails), and I've got it installed correctly, however, it always adds `<br>` tags and I'm trying to figure out how to remove it.

```
$('.redactor-go').redactor 
  'buttonHide': ['image'],
  'deniedTags': ['br']
```

I tried something like this above, but it doesn't work. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: have you tried disabling Linebreaks mode by passing `linebreaks: false`?

Comment: @AbM just tried, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround using `.gsub` and regex...

```
= auto_link(@user.notes.html_safe.gsub(/<br\s*\/?>/, ""),html: { target: '_blank' } )
```

I believe this eliminates all `br` tags: `<br>`, `<br />`, `<br/>`